# how to make a plot of an integral function?

Tags: matlab

I made an integral as follow :

```
fun = @(t)((2/sqrt(pi)) * (exp(1).^((-t).^(2))));
```

it works fine to calculate it :

```
q = integral(fun, 0, 2);
```

But I'd like to plot the result from 0 to different max (0 to 1, 0 to 2, etc...)

I tried

```
plot(A,fun, '-b');
```

and I cannot find another way to make it work. What would be the right way, and why isn't it working?

Comment: What exactly do you want to plot? Do you want to plot the integral result for different maxima?  The `x` axis being the maximum and the `y` axis is the integral?

Comment: exactly!! y the result, x being maximum

Comment: I've placed an answer.  However, I see this function quickly growing.  Make sure you choose maximum values that make sense for your function.

Comment: In addition to @rayryeng's answer, you could adapt the answer I [gave here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26557516/3121310) with a constant lower bound of `0` and no `cumsum` on the last line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you want to compute the integral at each maximum value, there's no way you can vectorize this because of the natural way you're calling `integral`.  As such, you have to put this into a `for` loop.

At each iteration in the loop, you'd compute the integral, put this into an array then plot the array.  Perhaps do something like this:

```
vals = 1:3; %// For different maxima - Change to suit your tastes

%// To store the integral results
q = zeros(1,numel(vals));

%// Your code
fun = @(t)((2/sqrt(pi)) * (exp(1).^((-t).^(2))));

%// For each value
for ii = 1 : numel(vals)        
    q(ii) = integral(fun, 0, vals(ii)); %// Find integral of each value
end

%// Plot the max value and integral pairs
plot(vals, q);
```

I get this:

[image]

Comment: if I would not be calling integral the way I do, would there be a simpler way?

Comment: @CherrysaHerrim - I don't understand. Can you clarify?

Comment: would there be a way to make the integral to be a function like x.^2? so I could only use by setting a vector called x.

Comment: @CherrysaHerrim - The call to `integral` makes you unable to do that.  `integral` can only take one lower and one upper bound at one time... even if the function is as simple as `x.^2`.  That's why you need a `for` loop.

Comment: I see... but then I tried something which didn't work, but with the right syntax, could I make a variable with the function x.^2 and then use it to make the integral? Like a handle.

Comment: @CherrysaHerrim - Yes. Just modify the `fun` variable - `fun = @(t) t.^2;`??

Comment: Shouldn't it be `for ii = numel(vals), q(ii) = integral(fun, 0, vals(ii)); end` ? In case `vals` is not of the form `1, 2, 3, ...`

Comment: @LuisMendo - it's `for ii = 1 : numel(vals)`, but yes :)

Comment: @rayryeng Oops, yes :-) So that must be why I wasn't getting the same plot with your code and mine. Now they are the same

Answer (score 3):

[`integral`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html) can only handle *numeric* values for the integration limits. To have a generic integration limit, you can define that limit to be a [*symbolic* variable](http://es.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/create-symbolic-numbers-variables-and-expressions.html) and carry out the integration symbolically, for which you use [`int`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/int.html). That gives you the integral as a symbolic function of the upper limit. Finally, particularize values for the upper limit and plot.

```
fun = @(t)((2/sqrt(pi)) * (exp(1).^((-t).^(2))));
syms y; %// variable that defines upper integration limit
q = int(fun, 0, y); %// symbolic function of upper integration limit
yValues = linspace(0,2,100); %// define actual values for integration limit
qValues = subs(q, y, yValues); %// particularize q for those values
plot(yValues, qValues) %// plot values
```

[image]