# Produce integration array as a function of integration limit in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, integral

I'm trying to use the function `integral` to return an array of integrated points

I have a function defined:

```
v = @(t) cos(t);
```

and I'd like to find the integrated function, `x(t)` for several such values stored in tvec:

```
tvec = linspace(0,10,1000);    
x = @(tf) integral(@(t) v(t),0,tf,'ArrayValued',true);
```

But it doesn't appear that Matlab allows the array valued bit to be the limit of integration, since `x(tvec)` results in error.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note: there is [a duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26554474/get-integrated-vector-values) with a much more efficient solution than this one.**

The problem is that `integral` only accepts scalar limits. In your example the integrand is scalar-valued, so you should omit the `'ArrayValued'` setting: that will allow MATLAB to vectorize the integration for each upper bound.

You can use `arrayfun` to feed each upper limit to `integrate`. Also, you can just pass `v`, a function handle to `integral`, no need to redefine an anonymous function for it locally:

```
v = @(t) cos(t);
x = @(tf) arrayfun(@(tmax) integral(v,0,tmax),tf);

tvec = linspace(0,10,1000);    
sinvec = x(tvec);
```

It seems to work:

```
figure;
plot(tvec,sin(tvec),'s-',tvec,sinvec,'o-');
legend('sin(tvec)','sinvec')
```

[image: result]

Comment: [My way's faster](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26557516/3121310). ;)

Comment: @Troy no doubt:D Think we should vote for dupe? Either that, or you should add a similar answer here.

Comment: I was thinking about that when I saw your answer.  The question is different, but the desired result is the same ... Is that a dupe or is there merit in both questions (i.e., I think this question is better posed than the one I linked to)?

Comment: Yes, this question is more self-contained, but the other one starts with "`I am trying to integrate the sine-function. My goal is to get not just the value of the area inbetween a certain distance but the specific values of the integrated course.`". That's exactly what our OP wants, only with `cos`. So I think it could be a valid dupe, and your solution should be *much* faster for larger problems. The latter makes me say that either we should vote for dupe (in which case readers get redirected to your answer), or you should add a specific answer here.

Comment: @AndrasDeak this does appear to be the same question (sorry!).  If you add your answer, I don't mind closing this one.  Alternatively, if Troy would like to add his answer here, I'll edit this one for greater clarity.

Comment: @anon0909 I believe your question is clear enough:) It should be fine if we close this one as a duplicate: both Troy's and my answer will be available, but people finding your question will see that there's another, prioritized question with an answer. If they check it out (and they should) they'll find Troy's more efficient solution. So I think you don't have to do anything (except voting for duplicate if you can do that on your own question). In the mean time I think I'll add a note on top of my answer indicating that the duplicate has a more efficient answer.

Comment: @TroyHaskin  I was initially concerned that Troy's solution (in dupe question) would accumulate error at the boundaries of several small integrals.  I confirmed these solutions are the same to within floating point precision (and that Troy's is much faster!) for several dX increment sizes.

Comment: @anon0909 thanks for the feedback:)