# Matlab: How to speed up integration (int) for computing Arc lengths?

Tags: performance, matlab, numerical-integration

As part of my code I build up a geometry for meshing, by calculating 2d arc lengths with integration.
Below is a sample code which does that:

```
fun=@(ss)integral(@(t)sqrt((r0+a1*cos(1*t)+a2*cos(2*t)+a3*cos(3*t)+a4*cos(4*t)+a5*cos(5*t)+a6*cos(6*t)+a7*cos(7*t)+a8*cos(8*t)).^2 ...
    + (-a1*1*sin(1*t)-a2*2*sin(2*t)-a3*3*sin(3*t)-a4*4*sin(4*t)-a5*5*sin(5*t)-a6*6*sin(6*t)-a7*7*sin(7*t)-a8*8*sin(8*t)).^2),0,ss);
```

Integration is on 't' and all other parameters are constant (i.e. r0, a1, etc)

But integration takes so long time, and since I try many different geometries it would be great if I can find a way around to speed up this integration which takes a bit long.

How can I compute the same integral in a more quicker way?

Comment: Could you give me an example to think about while I am reading through this equation?

Comment: @cameronroytaylor example of where I use this integration and geometry creation you mean?

Comment: Sorry, that was not a clear question.  Are you just changing 'r0' and all of the 'a' variables and leaving everything else in the equation constant?

Comment: @cameronroytaylor actually as `@(t)` shows the integration is on "t" and everything else remains constant in the integration. But my question is in a general way, I was wondering about speeding up integration in a general way for computing arc length.

Comment: I believe the main problem is that you're defining a function for the upper bound of the integral, and you keep recomputing the whole integral for every value of the upper bound. If this is the case, look at the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26554474/get-integrated-vector-values/26557516#26557516), you can set up a mesh for `ss` and compute the integral only bit by bit, each part only once.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use something alternative.

```
% Assuming you have a range of ss values to compute the integral for
ssValues = linspace(startValue, endValue, numberOfValues);

% Preallocate result array
arcLengths = zeros(size(ssValues));

% Use parallel processing
parfor idx = 1:length(ssValues)
    ss = ssValues(idx);
    fun = @(t) sqrt((r0+a1*cos(1*t)+a2*cos(2*t)+a3*cos(3*t)+a4*cos(4*t)+a5*cos(5*t)+a6*cos(6*t)+a7*cos(7*t)+a8*cos(8*t)).^2 ...
        + (-a1*1*sin(1*t)-a2*2*sin(2*t)-a3*3*sin(3*t)-a4*4*sin(4*t)-a5*5*sin(5*t)-a6*6*sin(6*t)-a7*7*sin(7*t)-a8*8*sin(8*t)).^2);
    arcLengths(idx) = integral(fun, 0, ss);
end
```

You need to enable and configure the parallel processing toolbox